# How to make NavigationRootViewController inside UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have one tab bar controller to connect with 5 UIViewController. It was connected correctly. But I want to make NavigationRootViewController for each UIViewController. How to make them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- (void)setupViewControllers
{
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

HomeViewController *mainViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController] autorelease];
mainViewController.shouldReloadCount = YES;
[mainViewController release];

MapViewController *currentLocationController = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:currentLocationController] autorelease];
[currentLocationController release];

FavoritesViewController *favouriteController = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *thirdNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favouriteController] autorelease];

[favouriteController release];

AllNotificationsViewController *notifController = [[AllNotificationsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AllNotificationsViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *fourthNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:notifController] autorelease];
[notifController release];


SettingsViewController *settingsController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *fifthNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController] autorelease];

[settingsController release];


tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController,fourthNavController,fifthNavController, nil];
firstNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"house.png"];
firstNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";

secondNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"];
secondNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Locator";

thirdNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fav.png"];
thirdNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Favorites";

fourthNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"];
fourthNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Activities";

fifthNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"];
fifthNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Settings";

//[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:tabBarController.view];

 }
```

Comment: You cant call `release` on autoreleased objects, the program will crash. So please, check `[firstNavcontroller release];`,`[secondNavcontroller release]` etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This explains how to add UINavigationController inside a tab in UItabBarController using Interface builder.

***1) Add a tab bar controller to main window

2) Replace the viewControllers inside the Tab Bar items with UINavigationControllers

3) Set the viewControllers as the rootViewController for the respective UINavigationControllers***